# Two each loops that output text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with 100 questions and right answers. I want to document.write question and right answer in new line. HTML markup is straight forward.

```js
$( ".qtext " ).each(function( index ) {

  $x =  $( this ).text() ;

console.log($x);

// document.write($x);
// document.write("<br>");

});
$( ".correct " ).each(function( index ) {

  $x =  $( this ).text() ;

console.log($x);

// document.write($x);
// document.write("<br>");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="formulation">
  <h4 class="accesshide">title</h4>
  <input type="hidden" name="q513920:15_:sequencecheck" value="3">
  <div class="qtext">
    <p><strong>question </strong></p>
  </div>
  <div class="ablock">
    <div class="answer">
      <div class="r0"><input type="radio" name="q513920:15_answer" disabled="disabled" value="0" id="q513920:15_answer0"><label for="q513920:15_answer0">answer</label> </div>
  <div class="r1"><input type="radio" name="q513920:15_answer" disabled="disabled" value="1" id="q513920:15_answer1"><label for="q513920:15_answer1">answer</label> </div>
  <div class="r0 correct"><input type="radio" name="q513920:15_answer" disabled="disabled" value="2" id="q513920:15_answer2" checked="checked"><label for="q513920:15_answer2">correct answer</label> <img src="https://estudijas.rtu.lv/theme/image.php/rtunew/core/1426259605/i/grade_correct" alt="Pareizi" class="questioncorrectnessicon"></div>
  <div class="r1"><input type="radio" name="q513920:15_answer" disabled="disabled" value="3" id="q513920:15_answer3"><label for="q513920:15_answer3">answer</label> </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="formulation">
  <h4 class="accesshide">title</h4>
  <input type="hidden" name="q513920:15_:sequencecheck" value="3">
  <div class="qtext">
    <p><strong>question </strong></p>
  </div>
  <div class="ablock">
    <div class="answer">
      <div class="r0"><input type="radio" name="q513920:15_answer" disabled="disabled" value="0" id="q513920:15_answer0"><label for="q513920:15_answer0">answer</label> </div>
  <div class="r1"><input type="radio" name="q513920:15_answer" disabled="disabled" value="1" id="q513920:15_answer1"><label for="q513920:15_answer1">answer</label> </div>
  <div class="r0 correct"><input type="radio" name="q513920:15_answer" disabled="disabled" value="2" id="q513920:15_answer2" checked="checked"><label for="q513920:15_answer2">correct answer</label> <img src="https://estudijas.rtu.lv/theme/image.php/rtunew/core/1426259605/i/grade_correct" alt="Pareizi" class="questioncorrectnessicon"></div>
  <div class="r1"><input type="radio" name="q513920:15_answer" disabled="disabled" value="3" id="q513920:15_answer3"><label for="q513920:15_answer3">answer</label> </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="formulation">
  <h4 class="accesshide">title</h4>
  <input type="hidden" name="q513920:15_:sequencecheck" value="3">
  <div class="qtext">
    <p><strong>question </strong></p>
  </div>
  <div class="ablock">
    <div class="answer">
      <div class="r0"><input type="radio" name="q513920:15_answer" disabled="disabled" value="0" id="q513920:15_answer0"><label for="q513920:15_answer0">answer</label> </div>
  <div class="r1"><input type="radio" name="q513920:15_answer" disabled="disabled" value="1" id="q513920:15_answer1"><label for="q513920:15_answer1">answer</label> </div>
  <div class="r0 correct"><input type="radio" name="q513920:15_answer" disabled="disabled" value="2" id="q513920:15_answer2" checked="checked"><label for="q513920:15_answer2">correct answer</label> <img src="https://estudijas.rtu.lv/theme/image.php/rtunew/core/1426259605/i/grade_correct" alt="Pareizi" class="questioncorrectnessicon"></div>
  <div class="r1"><input type="radio" name="q513920:15_answer" disabled="disabled" value="3" id="q513920:15_answer3"><label for="q513920:15_answer3">answer</label> </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Question repeat 100 times, here I just posted markup for one. So I managed to get loop to output all questions and then all correct answers.

Now the output is:

question
question
question
correct answer
correct answer
correct answer

What I would like to achieve is

Question
Correct answer

Question
correct answer

so on.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. What isn't working with your current solution?

Comment: It would be great if you post more HTML, to see the questions and answers so We could see the behaivoor and see how to resolve it, ty

Comment: @Yussef  I updated my html.

Comment: Avoid `document.write` and all will be fine on your project. Use `append` and similar methods. `document.write` is dangerous and only experts knows exactly the use cases. However, even experts don't use document.write, so it is for something.

Comment: On the other side, if you mark the correct answers on the HTML, all visitors can see what answer is the right answer. So you will have a problem...

Comment: So you just want to check all questions and output a list of the questions and the text of the right answer?

Comment: @RMo Yes, sir but in manner where Q:A Q:A not list of Q's and then list of A's

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude it is more not for users but me.  I dont mind console loggin everything it is just the output order is not the way I wanted. Now it is list of Questions and list of correct answers. I want it to be Question - answer and so on

Comment: Seems like Santi already got the answer in the making. Use a single loop and append both values concatenated with some html to wherever you want them :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need two loops, only one. Loop through the questions and lookup the correct answer using your `index` and jQuery's `.eq()`.

`index` refers to the current question in the loop (starting with `0`), and jQuery's `eq()` finds the `nth` occurrence of an element (also starting with 0).

```js
$( ".qtext " ).each(function( index ) {
    var x =  $( this ).text() ;
    var correct = $( ".correct " ).eq(index).text();
    console.log(x + ": " + correct);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="formulation">
  <h4 class="accesshide">title</h4>
  <input type="hidden" name="q513920:15_:sequencecheck" value="3">
  <div class="qtext">
    <p><strong>question </strong></p>
  </div>
  <div class="ablock">
    <div class="answer">
      <div class="r0"><input type="radio" name="q513920:15_answer" disabled="disabled" value="0" id="q513920:15_answer0"><label for="q513920:15_answer0">answer</label> </div>
  <div class="r1"><input type="radio" name="q513920:15_answer" disabled="disabled" value="1" id="q513920:15_answer1"><label for="q513920:15_answer1">answer</label> </div>
  <div class="r0 correct"><input type="radio" name="q513920:15_answer" disabled="disabled" value="2" id="q513920:15_answer2" checked="checked"><label for="q513920:15_answer2">correct answer</label> <img src="https://estudijas.rtu.lv/theme/image.php/rtunew/core/1426259605/i/grade_correct" alt="Pareizi" class="questioncorrectnessicon"></div>
  <div class="r1"><input type="radio" name="q513920:15_answer" disabled="disabled" value="3" id="q513920:15_answer3"><label for="q513920:15_answer3">answer</label> </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="formulation">
  <h4 class="accesshide">title</h4>
  <input type="hidden" name="q513920:15_:sequencecheck" value="3">
  <div class="qtext">
    <p><strong>question </strong></p>
  </div>
  <div class="ablock">
    <div class="answer">
      <div class="r0"><input type="radio" name="q513920:15_answer" disabled="disabled" value="0" id="q513920:15_answer0"><label for="q513920:15_answer0">answer</label> </div>
  <div class="r1"><input type="radio" name="q513920:15_answer" disabled="disabled" value="1" id="q513920:15_answer1"><label for="q513920:15_answer1">answer</label> </div>
  <div class="r0 correct"><input type="radio" name="q513920:15_answer" disabled="disabled" value="2" id="q513920:15_answer2" checked="checked"><label for="q513920:15_answer2">correct answer</label> <img src="https://estudijas.rtu.lv/theme/image.php/rtunew/core/1426259605/i/grade_correct" alt="Pareizi" class="questioncorrectnessicon"></div>
  <div class="r1"><input type="radio" name="q513920:15_answer" disabled="disabled" value="3" id="q513920:15_answer3"><label for="q513920:15_answer3">answer</label> </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="formulation">
  <h4 class="accesshide">title</h4>
  <input type="hidden" name="q513920:15_:sequencecheck" value="3">
  <div class="qtext">
    <p><strong>question </strong></p>
  </div>
  <div class="ablock">
    <div class="answer">
      <div class="r0"><input type="radio" name="q513920:15_answer" disabled="disabled" value="0" id="q513920:15_answer0"><label for="q513920:15_answer0">answer</label> </div>
  <div class="r1"><input type="radio" name="q513920:15_answer" disabled="disabled" value="1" id="q513920:15_answer1"><label for="q513920:15_answer1">answer</label> </div>
  <div class="r0 correct"><input type="radio" name="q513920:15_answer" disabled="disabled" value="2" id="q513920:15_answer2" checked="checked"><label for="q513920:15_answer2">correct answer</label> <img src="https://estudijas.rtu.lv/theme/image.php/rtunew/core/1426259605/i/grade_correct" alt="Pareizi" class="questioncorrectnessicon"></div>
  <div class="r1"><input type="radio" name="q513920:15_answer" disabled="disabled" value="3" id="q513920:15_answer3"><label for="q513920:15_answer3">answer</label> </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

As a stylistic choice, I've changed the scope of your `$x` variable to remain local, and I've removed the `$`. (Generally, this implies the variable refers to a jQuery *object*, not a string.)